# Explicitly fire custom command of kendo grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid with a custom command. Now issue is I want to fire that custom command for specific row but not able to do it.
Here is my code:

Grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<RxConnectEntities.UserDTO>
                ().Name("UserList")
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound(p => p.UserID).Visible(false);
                    columns.Command(command => { command.Custom("Select").Click("OnSelectRow"); }).Width("80px");
                    columns.Bound(p => p.LastName).Title("Last Name");
                    columns.Bound(p => p.FirstName).Title("First Name");
                })
                .Filterable(filterable => filterable
                .Extra(false)
                .Operators(operators => operators
                .ForString(str => str.Clear()
                .StartsWith("Starts with")
                .IsEqualTo("Is equal to")
                .IsNotEqualTo("Is not equal to")
                .Contains("Contains")
                ))
                ).ToolBar(x => x.Template("<a class='k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-export pull-right' title='Export to Excel' data-title='Users'><div class='k-grid-export-image k-icon'></div>Export To Excel</a>"))
                .HtmlAttributes(new { @Style = "height:580px" })
                .Sortable()
                .Groupable()
                .Scrollable()
                .Events(events => events.DataBound("onDataBound").ColumnShow("onColumnShow"))
                .Pageable(p => p.PageSizes(new int[] { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 }).Enabled(true).Refresh(true))
                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax().ServerOperation(true).PageSize(20)
                .Model(m => m.Id(p => p.PrescriberID))
                .Read(read => read.Action("GetUserList", "User").Data("PassData"))
                ))
```

Javascript:

```
function OnSelectRow(e) {
  var grid = $("#UserList").data("kendoGrid");
  var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
  alert("User Detail: " + dataItem.UserID + " " + dataItem.FirstName + " " + dataItem.LastName");
}
```

Now I have a textbox and a button, in textbox user enter UserID and I have to fire onSelectRow event of kendo grid for that UserID. I know this trick

```
var row = $("#" + gridName).data("kendoGrid").table.find('tr[data-id="' + id + '"]')
```

but it's not working for me. It is not giving me anything in row var.

Note: I am using asp.net mvc5 with c#.

Answer (score 1):

`data-id` is not put into the `<tr>` elements by Kendo Grid. It uses `data-uid` instead, which is a generated GUID id that is made by the `DataSource`.

You could get the uid for your item by doing:

```
var id = 123; // get the ID from the text box
var gridWidget = $("#" + gridName).data("kendoGrid");
var dataItem = gridWidget.dataSource.get(id);
var uid = dataItem.uid;
var row = .table.find('tr[data-uid="' + uid + '"]');
```

Of course you could probably simplify your button click handler to just:

```
// called from grid action
function OnSelectRow(e) {
  var grid = $("#UserList").data("kendoGrid");
  var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
  showDetails(dataItem);
}

// called by button outside grid
function OnSelectRowManually() {
  var id = 123; // get the ID from the text box
  var dataItem = $("#UserList").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.get(id);
  showDetails(dataItem);
}

// reusable code to show details
function showDetails(dataItem) {
  alert("User Detail: "
    + dataItem.UserID
    + " "
    + dataItem.FirstName
    + " "
    + dataItem.LastName");
}
```